# MYSQL SP not looping

Tags: mysql

I found a great SQL statement that will mask production data ([Howto generate meaningful test data using a MySQL function](http://moinne.com/blog/ronald/mysql/howto-generate-meaningful-test-data-using-a-mysql-function)).

I am attempting to add this as a stored procedure.

When i run the function from a query, it works perfectly.

However, when i call the function from a SP, the records are randomized, but with the same data.  How do I get the SP to randomized each record like the query call????

So if I run this:

```
UPDATE MAINTBL 
  SET first_name = (SELECT str_random('Cc{3}c(4)')),
    last_name = (SELECT str_random('Cc{5}c(6)')),
    email = (SELECT str_random('c{3}c(5)[.|_]c{8}c(8)@[google|yahoo|live|mail]".com"')),
```

I get this:

```
first_name || last_name  || email
===========================================================
Xstpvb     || Slbynwcigi || vgsbtnl_obpvhahigqkfte@live.com
Vohv       || Nyeaqbn    || rtrc_nkjotdkpxhsrf@google.com
Nkjpxqm    || Ogrosyjwi  || ystbfz.egrowrtsnq@live.com
Mdig       || Cccepmxlla || tqxuwz.jzwjfborpufpi@mail.com
```

But when Iput it in a SP:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mask_data;

CREATE PROCEDURE mask_data()
  BEGIN
    UPDATE MAINTBL 
      SET first_name = (SELECT str_random('Cc{3}c(4)')),
        last_name = (SELECT str_random('Cc{5}c(6)')),
        email = (SELECT str_random('c{3}c(5)[.|_]c{8}c(8)@[google|yahoo|live|mail]".com"')),
END;

Then call it from a query:
    call mask_data;
```

I get the same output in each record:

```
first_name || last_name  || email
Ofgtlmz    || Mndbynbepn || vpngah.vcaxkhhmgqkd@yahoo.com
Ofgtlmz    || Mndbynbepn || vpngah.vcaxkhhmgqkd@yahoo.com
Ofgtlmz    || Mndbynbepn || vpngah.vcaxkhhmgqkd@yahoo.com
Ofgtlmz    || Mndbynbepn || vpngah.vcaxkhhmgqkd@yahoo.com
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Makes sense.  Do you have an example i could use to get started?

Comment: xQbert is wrong here. Works absolutely fine for me. You don't need the `select`. Just do `...set first_name = str_random(...`.

Comment: FancyPant, you nailed it.  Removed the selects and vowla....magic.  Thanks m8!!!

Answer (score 1):

(to get this out of Unanswered)

Fixed by removing unnecessary `SELECTs`.